# AndroidStudio: BroadcastReceiver for established Wifi connection shows no result

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I am building a Smart Home system for me which uses a RaspberryPi as a central managing station in the home where a server is running that manages all data requests or sensor informations from all other devices within the Smart Home system. One of those devices is my smartphone, an android device. I designed an app where I can see all important information of my Smart Home. 
Now, when I enter the house and when my smartphone is connected to the Wifi, I want it to connect to the Smart Home server on the RaspberryPi to load current information or eventually generate a notification for me. Therefore, I created a BroadcastReceiver which should now activate the app to do what I want at the moment when the smartphone has a Wifi connection. However, that does not work and I don't know why. 

**In my "AndroidManifest.xml" file I inserted that tag into the application tag:**

[image: A receiver tag whith an intent-filter tag and three action tags]

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.test.checking.ConnectivityReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**The following class is my BroadcastReceiver:**
[image]

```
package com.example.test.checking;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "wifi_connection_channel";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Wificonnection established! I am happy!");
    }
}
```

**In my "AndroidManifest.xml" I also declared the permissions:**

[image]

I just put in a console output when the receiver's method is called but when I start a debug and turn off or on the Wifi connection on my smartphone, there is no message in the console. I've also tested a notification to be sent or an activity to be started but that did not work too.

Does anybody see what is my fault?
Thanks a lot!

**So the problem now is that I could register a broadcast receiver but only one that stays online while the app is opened or at least not fully closed. I do that using `getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`. Does anyone know how to create somethin (not necessarily a BroadcastReceiver) that checks the connection to the Smart Home server when a Wifi connection is established?**

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_70

Comment: Yes, I now read it and tried to use the information but I couldn't get it going..

Comment: So as you can see now in the edited post, I could set up a BroadcastReceiver but it is not doing what I want it to do...